# Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)

Tags: node.js, typescript, tslint

I am using Node with Typescript. I am finding a mongodb document and updating some values into it and then saving it.
On the statement save it is showing this error.
Below is the code:

```
let user = await User.findById(id);
if (user) {
  user = Object.assign(user, req.body);
  await user.save();  // on this line error is shown
} else {
  throw "User not found";
}
```

On the line await user.save() it is showing this error.

Comment: You tagged this as tslint, is this a tslint error or a hard typescript error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but mutating the `user` variable seems to be causing the issue.

Rewriting it with a new variable works fine in the typescript playground for me (I had to cheat a bit to avoid having a real Mongoose model and I made up the types, but it should be the same idea):

```
type User = {
    email: string;
    save: () => Promise<void>
}

declare let user: User | null;

if (user) {
  const newUser = Object.assign(user, { email: "test@example.com"})
  newUser.save();  // on this line error is shown
} else {
  throw "User not found";
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKCjqEC2AhgJYA2AXFHMIsQHYDmA3NrnIQG4SUAUAlKgB8UAAqIA9vmIIAPB3HEAJoMwBfTJkUQAxqUKJopCMCgBXBIkrwkUAD5Q6p0qRaZiAMyg9zSAVhza4nTUDhAA7tbIaADyAEYAVjrAAHSEcHDEDHTeFgA0GHhEZJQARMAQ1AACEAAehPhgRsmB+CWqfKx04ZHJ7Fz8TDgA9ENQQVDAABbSUKT00EgSyDNwk+JhdGp4pAgYrFMSYVAlkQ7iJu7ipnSKJSyqQA

Comment: that worked for me. Thanks. Still searching for the exact reason, If anyone gets do let us know.

Answer (score 1):

This means that user can be `null`.

You can use conditional statement:

```js
if(user){
 await user.save()
}
```

Or [optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining):

```js
await user?.save()
```

Comment: For the first solution of using conditional statement, you can see in the question i am using that, for the second one on building the code via npm run build it gets changed to user ? .save() ; so that is also not working.

Comment: You are right! Could you please share reproducable example

Comment: the above code can help you to reproduce, i think, you have to create a mongose model and then just call this above code in a function.

Comment: It is time consuming